# TV stand anchored to wood table

Tags: structural

I would like to put a TV stand like [this](http://www.leroymerlin.es/img/r25/22/2210/221001/18574850/18574850_f1.jpg) on the wood of a closet.

The TV is 20 kg weight. The weight is relatively small, but as the support allows an arm extension up to 50 cm, that means an important pair of forces (momentum) of 20*9.8*0.5 = 98 N*m.

The system would be reinforced by a rear stainless steel foil. That is, an steel plane at the back of the wood (2 mm thick, 4 cm wide, 75 cm long), 2 cm thick wood (from a piece of furniture 1 meter wide by 2 meters high) and the support, all that bolted together forming a "sandwich" steel-wood-support.

The furniture would be screwed to the wall, to avoid its overturning.

For the wood I think we can assume a resistance of 7 N * mm2. Steel, 240 N * mm2.

Any suggestions on how to make an evaluation about this structure ? Will wood break ?

This is a draft of the structure and detail of the anchor:

[image]

Comment: 20kg is _not_ a small weight for a TV or anything else that hangs.  By "closet" I guess you're talking about some type of cabinet?  I have a hard time picturing a piece of furniture with a back strong enough to support the TV on that mount - maybe a picture of the closet?

Comment: @JPhi1618: thanks for your interest in the issue. Some draw has been add.